# how to use apple push notifications using ios calendars built-in app and without an app

Tags: apple-push-notifications, icalendar

I have a client that created a custom mail server that has the calendars feature and wants the users to be able to sync their calendars in iOS Calendars built-in app.

I do not know how do this using the built-in iOS Calendars App.
I tried to setup in the Apple Development Account an app that use the Apple Push Notifications service but it looks like I have to create an application.

I didn't find any information on web.
Any suggestion where to start?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The "native" protocol for the iOS Calendars app is CalDAV. So what you really want is to have your server implement https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791

The Calconnect Developer's guide is a good source of information for such a project: https://devguide.calconnect.org/Table-of-Contents

It lists some server side libraries that you probably want to build your implementation on top of: https://devguide.calconnect.org/CalDAV/libraries/